# Getting Build Error in Yocto Build system

Tags: build, yocto

I am getting permission denied error when trying to build in yocto build environment.

Source code repository for Uboot I have kept it in gitlab.com and other build related dependencies I have kept in github.com.

I have downloaded(git clone) the built platform in my local machine. I made changes in source code in gitlab.com, and try to fetch and build using commit tag but getting permission error. If I doing the same in github.com(keeping source repository in github.com and make changes) not facing any issue.

I want to know the solution

**"Build failed error" posting from log file:**

> DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
>   NOTE: make -j 4 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- CC=arm-poky-linux->gnueabi-gcc  --sysroot=/home/cvp/prasenjit-bsp->platform/build/tmp/sysroots/prasenjit-novpek mx6slnovpek_config
>   make: execvp: /home/cvp/prasenjit-bsp-platform/build/tmp/work/prasenjit_novpek->poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-prasenjit-novpek/2014.07-r0/git/mkconfig: Permission >denied
>   Makefile:468: recipe for target 'mx6slnovpek_config' failed
>   make: *** [mx6slnovpek_config] Error 127
>   ERROR: oe_runmake failed
>   WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
>   ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/cvp/prasenjit-bsp-platform/build/tmp/work/prasenjit_novpek-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-prasenjit-novpek/2014.07-r0/temp/log.do_compile.29185)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in your uboot repository: For some reason the mkconfig script seems to not have executable permissions.

Comment: But if i give the path and used source code from github then no issue. if I give  the source code form git lab .com getting this build error. please help me if you have any information regarding thi

Comment: We dont know permissions of mkconfig and we dont know your code changes -> I dont know how to help you.
I also suggest to patch the original github repo with quilt.